# How to convert rgb to YCbCr?

Tags: color, image

I looked at [`ColorConvert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorConvert.html), but haven't found a relevant option. Is there a built-in function do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is using the digital formula given at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr). `ImageAdjust` was then used to scale computed YCbCR levels from `16..235` back to `0..1` for final display.

```
ClearAll[rgb2YCbCr]
rgb2YCbCr[{r_, g_, b_}] :=(*ref:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr, digital formula*)
  {16 + (65.481 r + 128.553 g + 24.966 b),
   128 + (-37.797 r - 74.203 g + 112 b),
   128 + (112 r - 93.786 g - 18.214 b)
   };

lena = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
lenaYCbCr = Map[rgb2YCbCr, ImageData[lena], {2}];
{red, blue, green} = MapThread[ImageMultiply, {ColorSeparate[lena], 
                      {Red, Green,Blue}}];    (*thanks to chat room for this trick*)

c1 = lenaYCbCr; c1[[All, All, {2, 3}]] = 1;
c2 = lenaYCbCr; c2[[All, All, {1, 3}]] = 1;
c3 = lenaYCbCr; c3[[All, All, {1, 2}]] = 1;

n = 300;
Grid[{
  {"RGB", "YCbCr", SpanFromLeft}, {Image[lena, ImageSize -> 350], 
   ImageAdjust[Image[lenaYCbCr, ImageSize -> 350]], SpanFromLeft},
  {Image[red, ImageSize -> n], "channel 1", ImageAdjust@Image[c1, ImageSize -> n]},
  {Image[green, ImageSize -> n], "channel 2", ImageAdjust@Image[c2, ImageSize -> n]},
  {Image[blue, ImageSize -> n], "channel 3", ImageAdjust@Image[c3, ImageSize -> n]}
  }, Alignment -> Center, Frame -> True,
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.5], LightGray]
 ]
```

This below shows the 3 channels of each image

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(for faster implementation of `rgb2YCbCr[]` please see MrWizard's code on this page)

Comment: Just as a side note, `lena2=Map[rgb2YCbCr, ImageData[lena], {2}]` should suffice instead of all those temporary variables.

Answer (score 7):

Despite all the efforts of Nasser and MrWizard to make this fast, I believe the most natural way to do this is to use [`ImageApply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageApply.html) because it is fast, it rescales the data for you and you don't have to extract the [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageData.html) by yourself. So taking the transformation matrix directly from Wikipedia for normalised RGB values and using their sample image too you get

```
img = Import[
  "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/Barns_grand_tetons.jpg"];
m = {{0.299, .587, .114}, {-.168736, -.331264, .5}, {.5, -.418688, -.081312}};
```

the conversion is simply

```
ImageApply[m.# &, img]
```

This is almost twice as fast as the solution of MrWizard on my machine here (0.640s compared to 0.356s), but note that this was only tested on *Mathematica* 8 and 9 on Linux and MacOSX.

Furthermore, be aware that the two colour channels are in the interval `[-0.5, 0.5]` so using `ColorSeparate` will produce very dark images in the last two channels.

If you want to create the visualisation of the different channels, which is shown on the right side [on the Wikipedia article page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr), you could simply use the inverse matrix. I shifted the colour channels by 0.5 here for display purposes

```
mi = Inverse[m];

ImageApply[#1, #2] & @@@ 
 Transpose[{{mi.{#, 0, 0} &, mi.{.5, # - .5, 0} &, mi.{.5, 0, # - .5} &}, 
   ColorSeparate[ImageApply[m.# + {0, .5, .5} &, img]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Timings

Regarding Mr.Wizards comment

> This is five times slower than my method on my system (v7). Before I reconsider my vote can you explain why this would be faster than Dot in later versions?

I compared the following timings,

```
ImageApply[m.#+{0.0,0.5,0.5}&, img] // Timing // First
RGBtoYCbCr[img] // Timing // First
```

where first line is the method I described with the shift of `{0,1/2,1/2}` included to make it more comparable to MrWizards method. The second line is the function from Mr.Wizards code.

Running this code 100 times to mean out cosmic radiation, I get the following mean timings

- Linux, *Mathematica* 9.0.1 halirutan: 0.305819 Mr.Wizard: 0.381984
- Linux, M8.0.4 halirutan: halirutan: 0.354542 Mr.Wizard: 0.394065

I believe the difference in timing is purely the overhead of pattern matching and `ImageData` call.

Comment: That vote-unvote was mine.  This is five times slower than my method on my system (v7).  Before I reconsider my vote can you explain why this would be faster than `Dot` in later versions?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to recreate that visualization yesterday so this made me glad. :) (btw `mi = Inverse[m];` is omitted). +1

Comment: @Anon Thanks, I fixed it. I haven't tried the code of my answer yesterday. Usually I do this and check whether everything works on a fresh kernel.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think I don't understand you last sentence in your comment. I use `Dot` too and I think the different timing has nothing to do with it. The real purpose of my answer was to show that you can do the conversion directly on the image with `ImageApply` and you are still very fast. (Btw, I have no version 7 installed where I could test it)

Comment: Pardon, I meant using `Dot` on the entire array at once versus using `ImageApply` to (seemingly) apply `Dot` to each triplet individually.  I wonder if there is some special compilation taking place in v8+ for `ImageApply`.  As I said it's slower in v7.  By the way is `m.# &+{0.0,0.5,0.5}` merely nonfunctional notation or is that also doing something special?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah, ok. I'm sure `ImageApply` is highly optimised internally. Maybe they even recognise simple `Dot` operations but I'm not sure. The last one is just a typo since I added the shift afterwards. I'll fix this.

Comment: FWIW you've got my vote now.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an array-optimized version of Nasser's formula.  It is up to two orders of magnitude faster.

It handles data with an array depth of 1, 2, or 3, or an `Image` object.

Timing comparision:

```
horse = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhYwB.jpg"];

Map[rgb2YCbCr, ImageData[horse], {2}] // Timing // First

RGBtoYCbCr[horse]                     // Timing // First
```

> 6.303
>
> 0.081

Sample output:

```
ImageAdjust @ Image[RGBtoYCbCr @ horse, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

---

#### Code:

```
With[{
  v1 = Developer`ToPackedArray @ {16`, 128`, 128`},
  m1 = Developer`ToPackedArray @ 
    {{65.481, 128.553, 24.966}, {-37.797, -74.203, 112`}, {112`, -93.786, -18.214}}
 },
 RGBtoYCbCr[a : {_, _, _}?VectorQ] := v1 + m1.a;
 RGBtoYCbCr[img_Image] := RGBtoYCbCr @ ImageData[img, "Byte"];
 RGBtoYCbCr[a_ /; MatchQ[Dimensions@a, {_, 3}]] := Transpose[v1 + m1.Transpose[a]];
 RGBtoYCbCr[a_ /; MatchQ[Dimensions@a, {_, _, 3}]] := 
   Transpose[v1 + m1.Transpose[a, {2, 3, 1}], {3, 1, 2}];
]
```

Answer (score 2):

A compiled version of Nasser's formula,

```
ClearAll[cRGB2YCbCr]
cRGB2YCbCr= Compile[{{rgb, _Real, 1}},
   {16 + (65.481 r + 128.553 g + 24.966 b), 
         128 + (-37.797 r - 74.203 g + 112 b), 
         128 + (112 r - 93.786 g - 18.214 b)} /.
        Quiet@Thread[{r, g, b} -> Array[rgb[[#]] &, 3]] // Evaluate,
    RuntimeAttributes -> Listable
   ];

horse = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhYwB.jpg"];
cRGB2YCbCr@ImageData[horse];//AbsoluteTiming
```